# now() change to static timestamp after creating view in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, sql-view

I have created a view in PGADMIN 4 to retrieve the data of last one month. This is my current code:

```
 Select * from test_1
 where productiondate >= ('now'::timestamp without time zone - '1 mon'::interval)
```

However, after I have created the view, it changed to this:

```
 productiondate >= ('2021-11-03 10:00:07.879988'::timestamp without time zone - '1 
 mon'::interval)
```

how to solve this thing?

Comment: FYI. this behavior is spelled out here [Date/Time functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) 9.9.5. Current Date/Time in the **Tip** at bottom of section. The section is worth reading for information on what the various functions are actually returning.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL statement that defines a view is parsed at the time the view is defined.

Use the `localtimestamp` function rather than a literal like `'now'::timestamp` to avoid the problem.